# Algorithm to find where exactly two strings match/differ

Tags: string, comparison, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I am working on finding the similarity/differences in the source code of different java programs.
I've used an implementation of the Levenshtein algorithm to find how similar two programs are.
I want to know if there is any algorithm that can help in finding the exact positions where two strings differ.

Comment: Do you know there are many excellent tools that do what you want? Any particular reason to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This is for a school project.So,I'm just looking to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find more than you ever wanted to know by looking at the inner workings of `diff` - see for example [this link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm) or simply the [wiki article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)